# Ext Js App bloated with stores

Tags: extjs, architecture, extjs4, extjs4.2

My app (Ext JS 4.2.1) contains many grid panels, and also that many stores. When defining a store I use the storeId to match grid and store. Many of these stores are almost identical. A sample store looks like this

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.UsersStore', {
     model: 'MyApp.model.User',
     storeId: 'UsersStore',
     proxy: {
         type: 'rest',
         url: 'somePrefix/users',
         reader: { 
             type: 'json', 
             totalProperty: 'total', 
             root: 'users'            
         } 
     }
});
```

Another store "AvailableUsersStore" looks quite similar, it just uses another url,  "somePrefix/users/?Available" and another storeId, "AvailableUsersStore". So I have a lot of quite redundant code lines in my app, distributed over many store files. Any idea how I can clean this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create base class for your store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.UsersStore', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
     model: 'MyApp.model.User',
     proxy: {
         type: 'rest',
         url: 'somePrefix2/users1',
         reader: { 
             type: 'json', 
             totalProperty: 'total', 
             root: 'users'            
         } 
     }
});
```

And then extend your base class:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.AvailableUsersStore', {
     extend: 'MyApp.store.UsersStore',
     storeId: 'userStore1',
     proxy: {
         url: 'somePrefix2/users2',
     }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.store.RemovedUsersStore', {
     extend: 'MyApp.store.UsersStore',
     storeId: 'userStore2',
     proxy: {
         url: 'somePrefix2/users3',
     }
});
```

Take a look [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/class_system) for class extending. And also take a look at [Deft.js](http://deftjs.org/) for flexible architecture in extjs.

Comment: I never to an explicit Ext.create on my stores, I just define them, and I think StoreManager will do an Ext.create on first access.

Comment: I suggest [Deft.js](http://deftjs.org/) for clean and maintainable architecture using extjs.

Comment: Wow, I never knew about that before. Thank you, this will help a lot!